# c# Turtle recursive function adding 1 angle

Tags: c#, recursion, drawing, turtle-graphics, angle

I saw [this video](https://vm.tiktok.com/ZSesmeMh2/) on TikTok and wanted to code it myself using c# Turtle, and I do know it should be easy but whatever I'm doing doesn't work like the video does.
Here's what I tried:

```
 Turtle t = new Turtle();
 t.TailDown();
 for (int i=0; i<1440; i++)
 {
   t.MoveForward(5);
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2);
   t.TurnRight(i);
 }
```

And it just does 2 and then repeats itself, I might just be dumb but also tried messing with some if statements but still couldn't get it to work like I wanted..

Comment: "it just does 2" what does this mean?